# SSIS for project online with ODATA Connection does not work

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis

We are working on an SSIS package to get data from project online with ODATA connection.

Steps to recreate:
1)  Create a new SSIS project in Visual Studio
2)  Create a new Data Connection with ODATA Data source. The test connection is successful.
3)  Create a new Data source and select the Data Connection created in the above step. This is where the Visual  Studio just spins and does not respond.

How would I see what the error log is, the visual studio just hangs and does not give out any output.

The ODATA endpoint URL is:
https://XXXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pwatest/_api/ProjectData/

With the same credentials if get the data from excel or even browser the data comes up correctly.

I am out of ideas on how to debug this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an add in like this [one](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/)? I had issues with ODATA source and went to that. We use connections to SharePoint so frequently that we bought this product [KingswaySoft](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/) It makes everything way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with the network. Running fiddler and enabling the listening on fiddler helped us proceed, we were still not able to run the package though, until the inbound connections were enabled in the network.